# Monitor a burst of events with inotifywait

Tags: linux, inotify, remote-control

I have a service which is sporadically publishing content in a certain server-side directory via `rsync`. When this happens I would like to trigger the execution of a server-side procedure.

Thanks to the `inotifywait` command it is fairly easy to monitor a file or directory for changes. I would like however to be notified **only once for every burst of modifications**, since the post-upload procedure is heavy, and don't want to execute it for each modified file.

It should not be a huge effort to come up with some hack based on the event timestamp… I believe however this is a quite common problem. I was not able to find anything useful though.

Is there some clever command which can figure out a burst? I was thinking of something I can use in this way:

```
inotifywait -m "$dir" $opts | detect_burst --execute "$post_upload"
```

Comment: If possible you could modify the remote rsync to add an option like ` -M --log-file=/some/path/log` which would make the local rsync keep a log of the changes in a local file you can wait for the close of.

Comment: @meuh I'm working through ssh, so there's no remote rsync. But maybe your suggestion could be the way to go otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing on your own answer, if you want to use the shell `read` you could take advantage of the `-t` timeout option, which sets the return code to >128 if there is a timeout. Eg your `burst` script can become, loosely:

```
interval=$1; shift
while :
do  if read -t $interval
    then    echo "$REPLY"            # not timeout
    else    [ $? -lt 128 ] && exit   # eof
            "$@"
            read || exit    # blocking read infinite timeout
            echo "$REPLY"
    fi
done
```

You may want to start with an initial blocking read to avoid detecting an end of burst at the start.

Comment: Ah! This seems really interesting! I'm totally trying it out asap

Comment: Interestingly, on zsh it returns 1 both upon timeout or if I'm reading from /dev/null. I'm going to use this on bash, so that's not a problem, but it's a good thing to know :)

Answer (score 2):

OP here. A possible <strike>solution</strike> hack could be similar to

```
inotifywait -m "$dir" -e moved_to --timefmt='%s' --format '%T' | stdbuf -oL uniq | ...
```

**EDIT:** *See my other answer to this question, since the second take is IMHO a better one*

It works by having the time since Epoch printed at every `move_to` is performed, which is the final step of a single-file transfer.

This works decently, even if it could trigger the post-upload procedure multiple times if one upload lasts more than one second.

A different granularity could be obtained by changing the `--timefmt` flag to some different value.

Posting it here as semi-decent idea, even though I don't like it much ...still I thought of sharing it.

Comment: Better make that `… | stdbuf -oL uniq | …` or you'll have some large pauses due to buffering.

Comment: I came out with another solution which is a bit better than this one. See my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Op here.

The solution I came out with: it is a script named `burst`:

```
inotifywait -e moved_to "$monitored_dir" -m \
    | burst 2 'echo run post-upload'
```

The `burst` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

help() {
    >&2 echo "Usage: $0 <interval> <command>"
}

set -e
trap help EXIT
interval=${1:?missing interval}; shift
: ${1:?missing command}

trap - EXIT
set +e
exec 3> >(sed "s/^/burst: /" >&2)
while read line; do
    echo "$line" >&3
    test -n "$!" && kill -term $! 2>/dev/null
    (sleep $interval && $SHELL -c "$*") &
done
```

Basically this is creating a subshell which waits a defined amount of time before launching the actual command (`(sleep $interval && $SHELL -c "$*")`. Any new line read by `inotifywait` will simply kill the such shell (if any exists) and create it again.

Once the burst of lines is over, the shell will be able to end the `sleep`,
and the command will be executed.

It has some drawbacks:

1. It kills and spawns one process for each line in stdin. Which means you want to
   reduce the number of lines first off (hence the `-e moved_to` filter in
   `inotifywait`). It could not fit w.r.t performance if the number of uploaded files is
   large enough!
2. If a second burst comes in after `$interval` seconds (or a file transfer
   takes that time) chances are it will kill the running post-update
   process. As long as such process is idempotent or transacted this will be
   fine… so heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop that checks the current time and skips events that are identical (or more generally, similar in a way you can define) to a previous event. In bash, ksh or zsh, the following simple loop skips repeated events in a 10-second period:

```
inotifywait -m … | {
  previous_SECONDS=0
  previous_event=
  while IFS= read -r event; do
    if [[ "$event" = "$previous_event" && $SECONDS <= $previous_SECONDS + 10 ]]; then
      continue
    fi
    previous_SECONDS=$SECONDS previous_event=$event
    "$post_upload" "$event"
  done
}
```

Shells are not good at high-performance text processing, so it may be better to use a different tool. You can use awk, which for historical reasons has a very strange way to expose the time (as number of seconds since the epoch): calling `srand()` returns the time of the previous call to `srand()`.

```
inotifywait -m … | awk '
    {srand(); current_time = srand()}
    $0 == previous_event && current_time <= previous_time + 10 {
        system(ENVIRON["post_upload"])
    }
    {previous_event = $0; previous_time = current_time}
'
```

Unless you really need the portability, I'd scrap this and use a more advanced scripting language such as Perl, Python or Ruby. These languages have an interface to inotify, so no need to call `inotifywait` and do any text parsing.

Comment: Yep, using a scripting language is also a possible solution. Also the `srand` story is crazy enough... my face when…